# 'Save html form data in database' django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I'm trying to save name and email from HTML from using django in postgres database, in action tag, function name is mentiond but insted of using that function, django is passing that data to a new page of same function name

HTML

```
<form class="newsletter_form d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between"  action="subscribe" method="post">
                                {%csrf_token%}
                                <div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-start justify-content-between">
                                    <div>
                                        <input name="subname" type="text" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_name" id="newsletter_input_name" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                                        <div class="input_border"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input name="subemail" type="email" class="newsletter_input newsletter_input_email" id="newsletter_input_email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required="required">
                                        <div class="input_border"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div><button type="submit" class="newsletter_button">subscribe</button></div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subname = request.POST['subname']
        subemail = request.POST['subemail']

        sub = User.objects.create_user(subname=subname, subemail=subemail)
        sub.save();

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("register", views.register, name='register'),
    path("login", views.login, name='login'),
    path("logout", views.logout, name='logout'),
    path("subscribe", views.subscribe, name='subscribe')
    ]
```

this is error

[image]

Comment: You have to provide action with `{% url 'subscribe' %}` in your template

Comment: same thing working with login and register page I haven't used {% url 'login' %} <form class="login100-form validate-form" autocomplete="off" action="register" method="post">

Comment: If you are using django default  user model to login/register then you  don't have to provide action.django handles itself.

Comment: @user11418935 this error I get when I used action="{% url 'subscribe' %}" https://imgur.com/a/IrflF98

Comment: why not try to use `ModelForm` provided by django ??

Comment: why are you adding a semi-colon @noobprogrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you are not redirecting using `redirect('/')` because when you redirect you you should use the name you assigned in `urls.py` i.e `path("register", views.register, name='register'),` the name here is ***register***

then in `views.py`:

```py
def subscribe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subname = request.POST['subname']
        subemail = request.POST['subemail']

        sub = User.objects.create_user(subname=subname, subemail=subemail)

        return redirect('subscribe')
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

what i edited is :

- deleted `sub.save()` because thats only used in django forms.

and about the subscribe url which causes 404 is you are not rendering a single template, how should the subscribe function work ?

call the `render()` function in the end of the subscribe function

and simple advice, add an ending slash in the end of every url pattern i.e `path("register/", views.register, name='register'),` :) this is advisable

Comment: subscribe form is on index.html and I'm rendering it on 

```
def home(request):
    dests = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'cities': dests})
```

Comment: thats simply not possible, make the form in `subscribe.html` and render this html in the `subscribe` function, OR, do the process above in `home` function. and i recommend the first one, its not good to make things like that in the `home` function. unless you want to make a form in all pages, in this case django forms will help you instead of making the form manually

Comment: I wan't my website to work like this [link]https://imgur.com/a/WoUGgeJ[link] this section will be at the end of the website

Comment: Image not available

Comment: Thats styling, either using the django forms and call it everytime you want it or do your way, and if you want it in every page then make in the `base.html`

Comment: thanks solved my issue, I moved the function in main app and also the big mistake was, I was using user object to save in not user table.